# How to convert JSObjectRef to JSValueRef

Tags: javascriptcore

I was using `JavaScriptCore C` APIs on Android, and I want to convert a map to `JSObject` without `stringify`:

```
JSObjectRef json = JSObjectMake(context, nullptr, nullptr);
for (int i = 0; i < keyCount; ++i) {
  std::string key = GetKeyName(keys, i);
  JSObjectSetProperty(context, json, ToJSString(context, key),
                      ToJSValue(context, MapGetAt(handle, key)),
                      nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

But at the end, I got a `JSObjectRef` instead of a `JSValueRef` which is the only type can return to `JSObjectCallAsFunctionCallback`.
I know `JSValueToObject` can convert `JSValueRef` to `JSObjectRef`, is there a function that can do the converse？

Answer (score 0):

Reinterpret cast will help you.
You don't need to call any additional function.
JSObjectRef is always JSValueRef.